# Override HTML DOM element methods JS

Tags: javascript, dom

***Short question:***

How may I **override** DOM built-in function as `document.getElementById ()` or build my **own** **method**, in *pure* JS?

---

***Explanations:***

I am working on an API which uses attributes to locate divs in my HTML page.

I can get the attributes of a div using this method:

```
for (var att, i = 0, atts = div.attributes, n = atts.length; i < n; i++) {
    att = atts[i];
    nodeName = att.nodeName; 
    nodeValue = att.nodeValue;
}
```

---

***Then***, I need to use this code to check the attributes of a given HTML object. I built a method which checks the **document's div's attributes**:

```
document.getElementByIdentifier = function (identifier) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.children.length; i++) {
         for (var att, i = 0, atts = div.attributes, n = atts.length; i < n; i++) {
            att = atts[i];
            nodeName = att.nodeName; 
            nodeValue = att.nodeValue;
            // Here I check the attributes
        }
    }
}
```

***However***, I can not **call this function from an [HTML Dom object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement)** (except, here, the `document` object). I do not find how to replace `document` by something like `allHTMLElements` in my method above. The goal is to have the same freedom of usage as `document.getElementById` for example.

*How may I do that?*

---

**Note:** I am very surprised because the `document.getElementById` seems to be located into the `document` object. However, when I try to build my own method into this object, it does not work. *Why?*

---

**Other note**: This is (*at least* for me) an **HTML DOM object**:`var A = document.getElementById ("C");`. Here the object A is an HTML Dom object calls: "object" by google chrome when I try `console.log (typeof A);`.

---

**Otherwise note:**

This is an example of one of my divs:

```
<script identifier="OAdgRzf"></script>
```

---

**Finally note**:

Use `document.querySelector` is the way I am already using on my library. However, I now have to run updates and tests for elements which are called by the user. I built a function which uses `document.querySelector` and then runs tests but it is not very pretty.

---

*Tell me a comment if you have some questions.*

Comment: Just out of curiousity, why would you want to build a custom method for something that is already there as a built-in function?.

Comment: Just wondering, why do you need to do your own method, would `document.querySelectors` not work for you?

Comment: @AndrewL, My library uses a special attribute to locates divs. This attribute cannot be found with a built-in method (or at least I do not know it). I need to create a built-in method to make easily the interaction user-library.

Comment: `document.querySelector('[whateverAttributeYouHave]')` will find any element with whatever attribute

Comment: Can you post some sample DOM that includes divs with the special attributes you mention?

Comment: `document.querySelector('div[special-attribute="potatoSalad"]')` querySelector( as mentioned by @Pytth ) should let you query by special attributes of your divs.  It's always dicey to hack core functionality.

Comment: I'm confused - the DOM you added is a `script`, not a `div`

Comment: @ic3b3rg, the best for me is to use this method for all HTML DOM objects such as img, script, i, b, canvas...

Comment: For your example: `document.querySelector('[identifier="OAdgRzf"]')`

Comment: For all, it is better if users can call a method for a specific HTML element (at least it is more pretty than a simple function using for example querySelector). Please note that I also have to run tests/checks when an element is called.

Comment: If you want a specific *type* of element, add its type outside the `[...]` i.e. for a `div` use `document.querySelector('div[identifier="OAdgRzf"]')`

Comment: "I built a function which uses document.querySelector and then runs tests but it is not very pretty." <<-- What exactly do you mean by **not very pretty** here? `querySelector` is as straightforward as it can be tbh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To repeat what's going on up in the comments; please, please, **PLEASE**, do not try and hack core functionality.  If you would like to create a custom method to use in your code you can extend the `Object` object...

```js
Object.prototype.getEl = function( selector ){
 return document.querySelector( `[special-attribute="${selector
}"]` );
}
console.log( document.getEl('potatoSalad') );
```

```html
<div special-attribute="potatoSalad">one two three</div>
```

This way you can have the more condensed call `document.getEl()` to target your desired elements while still preserving the original methods in JavaScript.

It may be possible to hack the core code; but it is very strongly recommended to not attempt this.  As everyone discovers when they go down this path, it normally results in unexpected errors in the code -- where things are connected and it was not immediately known.

Comment: It is exactly what I need! Thank you for your work! I also code in C++ where it is quite common to override built-in functions, I thought I can do the same thing in JS. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> *This attribute cannot be found with a built-in method (or at least I*
>   *do not know it)*

Yes there is a built-in method for finding special attributes and that method is called **[querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)** or if you want to retrieve more than one object, there is **[querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)** that will return a list (called NodeList) of the document's elements that match the specified group of selectors.

---

Assuming you have a div with the attribute **`someWeirdAttribute`** like this:

```
<div someWeirdAttribute="someWeirdValue">
    Hello World
</div>
```

You can find the above element like this:

```
document.querySelector('[someWeirdAttribute="someWeirdValue"]');
```

---

Or if you want a more practical example, let us retrieve the attribute value as well as the div content from the above in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/4q7oLnte/12/) or in the code snippet below:

```js
/* JavaScript */
var div = document.querySelector('[someWeirdAttribute="someWeirdValue"]');
var output = document.getElementById('info');
var btn = document.querySelector('button');

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var attrVal = div.getAttribute('someWeirdAttribute');
    var divContent = div.textContent;
    console.log(attrVal);
    output.innerHTML = '';
    output.innerHTML += `<p>The div atrribute value of <strong>someWeirdAttribute</strong> is <strong>${attrVal}</strong></p>
    <p>The content inside the div is <strong>${divContent}</strong></p>`
})
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<div someWeirdAttribute="someWeirdValue">
    Hello World
</div>
<hr>
<button>
Get info about above element
</button>

<div id="info"></div>
```

Comment: A handy dandy thing I like to do with the default `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` is to make shortcuts to them: `var _ = document.querySelector.bind(document);` This makes `document.querySelector(...)` become `_(...)`.

Comment: @MarcusParsons That is a really simple yet nice trick to use especially if there are a lot of variable assignments I have to make. It also makes the variable assignment section of my JS look cleaner. I honestly never thought of doing that before.Thanks for the tip man!! Will definitely start implementing this now.

Comment: Absolutely! I forgot to mention `document.querySelectorAll` as well.  My assignment for that is usually: `var __ = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);` which of course makes `document.querySelectorAll(...)` become `__(...)`